# File cant be assigned with ImagePicker Flutter

Tags: flutter

i am learning imagepicker from https://pub.dev/packages/image_picker ,
but i don't why i got an error when i have use the way step by step.

this is the problem :

first, i declare a File variable

```
File _imageFile ;
```

then i use it in a method,

```
_getimg() async{
var _img = await ImagePicker(source: ImageSource.gallery);
setState(() {
      _imageFile = _img ;
    });
}
```

and then i got this error :

> A value of type 'File (where File is defined in
>   D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\io\file.dart)' can't
>   be assigned to a variable of type 'File (where File is defined in
>   D:\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\html\html_dart2js.dart)'.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is a conflict between Files declaration. The `html` package has one declaration of a class `File` and the `io` package has another declaration (same name, different origin).

In fact, using `html` is for web and `io` is used for console, server or mobile apps, so check your imports and delete `io` or `html` depending in the type of project you are working on.

Another solution is to define your imports like this:

```dart
import 'package:html/html.dart' as h; //"h" can change, is just an example
import 'dart:io' as i; //"i" also can be another char or word, is just an example

//And when you need to create a File,
//you can decide if you want to create
//an io File or an html File

main(){
    i.File f1 = ...; //The io File, starting with "i."
    h.File f2 = ...; //The html File, starting with "h."
}
```

Comment: which one i have to use, io or html when i want to declare file for imagepicker?

Comment: The io File. image_picker only works on mobile devices, so go with that :-)