# First Flutter Application and i got stuck with an error

Tags: file, flutter, imagepicker

i was trying to pickup image from gallery and update it to UI. But on performing this it shows an error in profile.dart file at line 56.

The error occurs at _image.

> The argument type 'File(where File is defined in
>   D:\Softwares\flutter\bin\cache\pkg\sky_engine\lib\html\html_dart2js.dart)'
>   can't be assigned to the parameter type 'File(where File is defined in
>   D:\Softwares\flutter\bin\caches\pkg\sky_engine\lib\io\file.dart)'

the complete code.

**Main.dart**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/SplashScreen.dart';
import 'package:udharibook/Screens/UserProfile.dart';

void main(){
  runApp(
      MaterialApp(
        title: 'Udhari Book',
        home:UserProfile(),
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        theme: ThemeData(
            backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(242, 242, 242, 1.0)
        ),
      )
  );
}
```

**ProfilePage**

```
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';
import 'package:firebase_storage/firebase_storage.dart';
import 'package:path/path.dart';

class UserProfile extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _UserProfileState createState() => _UserProfileState();
}
class _UserProfileState extends State<UserProfile> {
  File _image;
  TextEditingController nameController =TextEditingController()..text='Mehul Jain';
  TextEditingController mobileController =TextEditingController()..text='8856061841';
  TextEditingController emailController =TextEditingController()..text='mehuljain3698@gmail.com';
  TextEditingController addressController =TextEditingController()..text='Maharashtra';
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Future getImage() async{
      var image=await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);

      setState(() {
        _image=image as File;
        print('Image Path $_image');
      });
    }
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: false,
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('User Profile'),
        backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
      ),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (context) => Container(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: 20.0,
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 50,
                      backgroundColor: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: SizedBox(
                            height: 180.0,
                            width: 180.0,
                            child:_image!=null?
                             Image.file(_image,fit: BoxFit.fill):
                            Image.network(
                              'https://randomwordgenerator.com/img/picture-generator/55e4d5464f5ba914f1dc8460962e33791c3ad6e04e5074417d2d73dc934bcd_640.jpg',
                              fit: BoxFit.fill,
                            )),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 60.0),
                    child: IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(Icons.camera_alt), onPressed: () {
                          getImage();
                    }),
                  )
                ],
              ),
              Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:20.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
                  child:SizedBox(
                    height: 40.0,
                  child: TextField(
                    controller: nameController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: 'Full Name',
                        labelStyle:
                            TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                        border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                        ),
                        focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                color:
                                Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)
                            )

                        )
                    ),
                  ),
              )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
                child:SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: mobileController,
                  enabled: false,
                  keyboardType:TextInputType.phone,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Mobile Number',
                      labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color:
                              Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0),
                child:SizedBox(
                  height: 40.0,
                child: TextField(
                  controller: emailController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Email (Optional)',
                      labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color:
                              Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)
                          )

                      )
                  ),
                ),
              )),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top:15.0,left: 10.0,right: 10.0,bottom: 30.0),
                child: TextField(
                  maxLines: 3,
                  maxLengthEnforced: true,
                  controller: addressController,
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                      labelText: 'Address (Optional)',
                      labelStyle:
                      TextStyle(fontFamily: 'Exo2', color: Colors.grey),
                      border: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0)
                      ),
                      focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
                          borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color:
                              Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0)
                          )
                      )
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                children: <Widget>[
                  SizedBox(
                    width:130.0,
                  height: 50.0,
                  child:RaisedButton(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: Text(
                      'Save',
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color:Colors.white,fontSize: 22.0,fontFamily: 'Exo2'
                      ),
                    ),
                  )),
                  SizedBox(
                    width:130.0,
                  height:50.0,
                  child:RaisedButton(
                    color: Color.fromRGBO(162, 42, 43, 1.0),
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(18.0)
                    ),
                    onPressed: (){
                      Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    },
                    elevation: 4.0,
                    splashColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                    child: Text(
                      'Cancel',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color:Colors.white,fontSize: 22.0,fontFamily: 'Exo2'
                      ),
                    ),
                  ))
                ],
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome To Flutter. I am sorry that you are experiencing this error! Trust me, Flutter is really User friendly so soon you will get the hang of it :)

So it appears that this error is appearing due to a conflict within 2 or more imports that use File. Look at this thread: [File cant be assigned with ImagePicker Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59553494/file-cant-be-assigned-with-imagepicker-flutter)

Comment: @MJ Great man. If my help was any good could you please select it as the answer :)